# R function set.seed() or kmeans does not work in Power BI R script

Tags: r, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to compute and visualize cluster analysis from R in Power BI desktop. I use `set.seed()` function to prevent clusters (create with function `kmeans` from changing over time. I run this code first in Power BI Desktop and next time i publish it and run it in Power BI services. And here is the problem, because in Power BI desktop it make different (different order) clusters then in Power BI services.

A part of R code is:

```
set.seed(123)
km.res <- kmeans(scale(costs_noout_of), 4, nstart = 25)

dd <- cbind(costs_noout_all
            , cluster = km.res$cluster)

grid.table(ddply(dd, .(cluster), nrow))
```

And result is a table where is only numbers of clusters and counts of observations in that clusters, which i need in the following calculations.

Can anyone helps me?

Comment: Have you tried running `set.seed(123); runif(10)` in both instances? Do the results differ?

Comment: @RalfStubner this function works well. Do you think, that is possible, that problem is in the function kmeans?

Comment: Difficult to tell since I have no Power BI to test. I can only conclude that `set.seed` is not the problem.

Comment: @RalfStubner ok, thanks for the effort

Comment: Perhaps there is a different default RNG generator between the platforms. The output of `RNGkind()` might offer some insight.

Comment: @James in both platforms is output of `RNGkind()` the same - Mersenne-Twister and Inversion

Comment: It's a bit of a mystery then. I suspect the Azure platform is causing issues somehow. You could `sort` the output to ensure a consistent ordering though.